# C#: How to create custom exception from ValidationEventArgs exception, when validating an XML using XSD

Tags: c#, xml, exception, xsd

I have an XML file that is validated against an XSD file.
When a validation exception occurs, the handler is called:

```
ValidationCallBack(object sender, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs args)
```

I have the exception thrown by the framework, but I need to customize this exception in order to have the XSD line that have thrown this error and also the value from the XML that was not correct. 
Can I parse the exception's message in order to extract this kind of information? I mean, can I rely on a regular expression for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, by using the xmlns:ex="anySchemaNamespace" attribute for the xsd document element. Then, I can add for example this unhandled attribute ex:exception="My custom exception" to any element and then take that custom exception message from the element in code, when an exception occurs.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information from `Exception` member.

```
static void ValidationCallback(object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
{
    // Not sure if the exception is guaranteed to not be null.
    if (args.Exception != null)
    {
        // Remember to always retain the InnerException (last argument is args.Exception).
        throw new MyException(args.Exception.LineNumber, args.Exception.LinePosition, args.Exception.Message, args.Exception);
    }
    // If the exception is null do what we can.
    throw new MyException(-1, -1, args.Message, args.Exception);
}
```

**EDIT**: Just noticed that you wanted the original element/thing that caused the problem. Firstly, you can get the schema entity that caused the validation problem from `SchemaObject`. Getting the original item that caused the problem is way more difficult. You are probably going to have to re-read the document (with a non-validating reader) and search for the node with the matching line/position.

**Side note:** Please don't use regex, ever. You will get really nasty problems if your application is run on another locale: as all the built-in .Net exceptions have translations (so your regex won't work).

Comment: The thing is that is need to throw a custom message to the client for that exception, and I can't throw args.Message. Can you think of a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the details of the validation exception by looking at the public properties of the [XmlSchemaException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaexception.aspx) class (the instances of which are available via the `Exception` property of the `args` argument):

- LineNumber
- LinePosition
- SourceSchemaObject

Comment: Yes, I know but I need an array[] of values that contains: range expected, value received, the node name from the XSD, and so on. Can you think of a solution? Please.

Comment: I have found the solution, by using the xmlns:ex="anySchemaNamespace" attribute for the xsd document element. Then, I can add for example this unhandled attribute  ex:exception="My custom exception"    to any element and then take that custom exception message from the element in code, when an exception occurs. Thanks for your answers.